# How can one document a function with a variable number of arguments in YARD?

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

I have a function that take a variable number of arguments, like this:

```
def myfun(*args)
  # ...
end
```

All args are of the same type (`Symbol`), so right now I document the function like if there were only one argument, saying it can take more than one, e.g.:

```
# this function doesn’t do anything
# @param [Symbol]: this argument does something, you can add more symbols
#                  if you want
def myfun(*args)
  # ...
end
```

Is there a built-in way to handle this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following makes sense because `args` is an `Array` inside the method, although none of the params are an `Array` as such:

```
# this function doesn’t do anything
#
# @param [Array<Symbol>] args these arguments do something
# @return [nil]
def myfun(*args)
  # ...
end
```

Note the `*` is dropped from the param name in the comment. This is just to be consistent - `args` *is* an `Array`, but `*args` is not.

A quick search shows quite a few projects using this style, including inside Yard's own .rb files (e.g. see [source for initialize in Verifier class](https://github.com/lsegal/yard/blob/master/lib/yard/verifier.rb)) - although no examples of this convention are given in the guide.

Answer (score 4):

[Neil Slater's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23328895/27358) is as far as I know the best one for an unstructured argument list.

But for methods that use `*args` to accept any of a fixed set of possible parameter lists, there's [`@overload`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#overload). E.g., for [`Enumerable#find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index), one could write something like:

```rb
# Compares each entry in _enum_ with value or passes to _block_.
# Returns the index for the first for which the evaluated value
# is non-false. If no object matches, returns `nil`.
# 
# @overload find_index(value)
#   Finds the first index of the specified value.
#   @param value [Object] the value to find
#   @return [Integer, nil] the index, or `nil` if no element matches
# @overload find_index(&block)
#   Finds the index of the first value matching
#   the specified block.
#   @yieldparam [Object] element the element to match against
#   @yieldreturn [Boolean] whether the element matches
#   @return [Integer, nil] the index, or `nil` if no element matches
# @overload find_index
#   @return [Enumerator] a new enumerator
def find_index(*args)
  # (...)
end
```

This will get documented as:

> **#find_index**(value) ⇒ Integer<sup>?</sup>
> **#find_index** {|element| ... } ⇒ Integer<sup>?</sup>
> **#find_index** ⇒ Enumerator
>
> Compares each entry in *enum* with value or passes to *block*.
> Returns the index for the first for which the evaluated value
> is non-false. If no object matches, returns `nil`.
>
> **Overloads:**
>
> **#find_index**(value) ⇒ Integer<sup>?</sup>
>
> Finds the first index of the specified value.

(...etc.)