# With 'yard', how can I document a wildcard parameter like "def foo(*args)"

Tags: ruby, yard

Say I have a method like this

```
# @return [Integer] number of arguments provided to the method
def return_number_of_arguments(*args)
  return args.length
end
```

How could I add `@param` documentation?

Ideas I have:

```
@param [*Object] any objects
```

but I couldn't find anything in [the yard docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md)

Answer (score 1):

Since `args` will be splatted to an `Array` within the method body, I'd write

```
# @param args [Array] elements to count
# @return [Integer] number of arguments provided to the method
def return_number_of_arguments(*args)
  return args.length
end
```

Comment: I don't see what the point of this would be. For example if a method takes any number of successive strings arguments, it would be counterproductive to document it as taking an array, right?

Comment: @maxpleaner I see your point. I'm looking at how the passed argument will be treated internally – not necessarily the best POV for API docs. Apparently the `@overload` tag exists for that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416185/best-way-to-document-splatted-parameter-with-yard?rq=1